# Spring Reactive SecurityContext in Async Event Listener

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-async

We are using Spring WebFlux for our reactive Spring Boot application. We have successfully implemented authentication, thanks to which we can obtain an authenticated user using the `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder` class in REST API calls.

I have a method which publishes an event using the `ApplicationEventPublisher` instance. This method is called from a REST endpoint requiring user authentication, during which the authenticated user is available.

I also have an event listener marked with `@Async` and `@EventListener` annotations, in which I would like to retrieve the authenticated user from the original service call.

For servlet applications, I noticed I could use the `DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor`, but this unfortunately does not work for reactive applications.

Can the security context propagation be achieved in a reactive stack?